# Logout user in DB using recurring stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In our MSSQL database we have a table 'users'.
In that table we have a couple of columns.
2 of these columns are 'isOnline' and 'lastUpdated'.
When a user logs in, we set the flag 'isOnline' to 1.

We want to check with a recursive stored procedure (lets say each 30s) that 'lastUpdated' is more than 15min.

If it is, we want to set the 'isOnline' flag to 0.

Never done that before, so any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a scheduled job that will run the stored procedure on a specific schedule.

> **To create and attach a schedule to a job**
>
> - In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of the SQL Server Database    Engine, and then expand that instance.
> - Expand SQL Server Agent, expand Jobs, right-click the job you want to    schedule, and click Properties.
> - Select the Schedules page, and then click New.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with William Xifaras' answer

```
Update Users Set isOnline = 0
 Where DateDiff(MINUTE,lastUpdated,GetDate())>=15
   and isOnline = 1
```